# getBytes(int start, int end, byte[] data, int index) in Android

Tags: android, character-encoding

I am trying to use `getBytes(int start, int end, byte[] data, int index)` method in my sample android App and tested in emulator.

I found that the method works fine in Android 2.0 - 2.3

But in case of Android 3.0 - 3.1 it throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.opview);

        String test="TEST1234";
        byte [] bb = new byte[10];
        test.getBytes(0, 4, bb, 6);
        Log.i("TAG", "Output :"+(new String(bb)));
        Log.i("TAG", "OnCreate() End ");
    }
```

Also, I see that there is no way a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can occur because my input does not come under the conditions below

> if start < 0, end > length(), index < 0 or end - start > data.length -
>   index.

Is there any encoding problem in Android 3.0?

Any workaround for my problem ?

Comment: Your question is too vague, you need to provide some sample code, stacktrace or stuff we can see too help you !

Comment: Added the sample code please try this in Android 3.0 you will get an exception. Whereas in Android 2.1 it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look through the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html), you will see that `getBytes(int start, int end, byte[] data, int index)` has been deprecated. You are to use either `getBytes()` or `getBytes(String)`.

This is most likely why it is behaving weird in Android 3.0.